# How to loop through the elements of a Sequential in Scala?

Tags: scala, function, sbt

Consider this code in Scala (SBT):

```
abstract class Farm
case class Pig (length:Int, height:Int) extends Farm
val barn1 = Sequential (List (Pig (50 , 30), Pig (55 , 32) ) )
```

Now I want to define a function to loop through `barn1`:

```
def playSequential (?1):Unit = {
  ?2
}
```

What should I add instead of the `?`?

- `?1`: Which input type (cf. `k:Int` do I need?
- `?2`: How to define a for loop that loops through `barn1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
abstract class Farm
case class Pig (length:Int, height:Int) extends Farm
val barn1 = List(Pig (50 , 30), Pig (55 , 32))

def playSequential(barn: List[Farm]):Unit = {
  barn.foreach{
    case Pig(l,h) =>  // do something with length (l) and height (h) of this Pig
    case Cow(l,h) =>  // do something with length (l) and height (h) of this Cow
    case _ =>         // unknown element, report error
  }
}
```

I don't know what `Sequential` is (it's not standard Scala) so I removed it.